# How can I Insert data into a SQL table and default the rest

Tags: sql

For example, if I have the table `TestTable`:

```
|Name |Date |Data1|Data2|.....|
```

Where `|.....|` is the rest of the columns.

I want to insert the `Name` and `Date` with data and default the rest of the columns.

The command:
`INTSERT INTO TestTable VALUES('GreenSaber','2019-12-05', DEFAULT VALUES)` will not work.

Is there a way to make a command like the one above?

Comment: just insert into the columns you want.

Comment: You need to include the column names. `INSERT INTO TABLE (col1, col2) VALUES (val1, val2)`. This is assuming your DBMS is compatible with this syntax but you did not tag a DBMS so I am going to assume it is.

Comment: specify only those columns in the insert statement that will have data, and simply do not list the rest. the others columns must be NULLable. NULL will go into the rest of the columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should list the columns you want to insert:

```
INSERT INTO TestTable (Name, Date)
    VALUES('GreenSaber', '2019-12-05');
```

All unmentioned columns will be given default values.  If no explicit default is specified, the default is `NULL`.  If no default is specified and an unspecified column is `NOT NULL`, you will get an error.

Comment: Ok, I didn't set the defaults, that was the problem. Thank you!